# Socket.io server not receiving 'disconnect' event when client calls disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm playing around with socket.io on node.js (both client and server), and having trouble with the 'disconnect' event. Take a look at the following mocha test code:

```
it('This test never finishes', function(done) {
  // Output:
  // connected socket iYTGdwMJ0yVM5orGAAAB

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('connected socket', socket.id);
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('io disconnect');
      done();
    });
  });

  const mj = ioClient(`https://localhost:${socketPort}`);

  mj.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('mj disconnect');
  });

  mj.disconnect();
});

it('This test works', function(done) {
  // Output:
  // connected socket DNUREuytEp1CPJdFAAAC
  // io disconnect

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('connected socket', socket.id);
    console.log(io.socket.connected);
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('io disconnect');
      done();
    });
    socket.disconnect();
  });

  const mj = ioClient(`https://localhost:${socketPort}`);

  mj.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('mj disconnect');
  });

  // Looks like this has no effect
  mj.disconnect();
});
```

When `disconnect` is called on the client, why does the server not trigger the `socket.on('disconnect', ...)` listener?

Comment: Have you tried making any other connection with client and server? Do they communicate at all? Try emitting a test `socket.emit('test', true)` then see if you receive it

Comment: @serendipity yes that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a typical synchronicity problem (*read explanations in code comments*).

```
// This code will try to connect the server - 
// but the connection process is asynchronous
const mj = ioClient(`https://localhost:${socketPort}`);

// Now you subscribe to the disconnect event which is fine
mj.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('mj disconnect');
});

// And now you try to disconnect immediately which is done synchronously
// but how do you want to disconnect since you are still not connected ...
mj.disconnect();
```

What you can do is to try to disconnect once you make sure that you are connected :)

```
const mj = ioClient(`https://localhost:${socketPort}`);

mj.on('connect', () => {

    // Subscribe to disconnect event once you know you are connected
    mj.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('mj disconnect');
    });

    // Now disconnect once you are connected 
    mj.disconnect();
});
```